# Why the SpringBoot jar file can be deleted when it is still running?

Tags: spring-boot

The website is a SpringBoot project. And it is deployed in Linux server. It turns out that the jar files can be deleted when the website is still running. This is quite different from windows.

In windows, once the dll file is loaded into memory, that file will be locked by that process and other process cannot delete that file. But in Linux, it seems there is no such lock.

Some says that

> Deleting a file that is open in Unix deletes its name from the disk, the file itself is only deleted when it is closed.

There is also some suspect that

> The file is actually deleted. Because it has been loaded into memory, so the program can still run.

What is under the cover? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you really mean to compare _deleting a jar file_ to _deleting a dll_? The JVM loads the contents of the jar into memory and does not access the physical file any longer. This is regardless of the OS.

Comment: @ Randy Casburn, is there any lock in Linux for used file? In windows, if a file is loaded into memory for one process, it will be locked and cannot be deleted.

Comment: Apples to Apples - run your jar file on Windows. And while it is running try to delete the jar file. What happens?

Comment: No. It cannot be deleted in windows. The jar is locked by that process.

Comment: This is a legit question. I can delete my jar file on a linux system, although i am connecting to it via SSH. I wonder how can i do it.